# What is the difference between SftpClient.UploadFile and SftpClient.WriteAllBytes?

Tags: c#, .net, ssh, sftp, ssh.net

I am observing some strange behaviour when I use SSH.NET to transfer files with SFTP. I am using SFTP to transfer XML files to another service (which I don't control) for processing. If I use `SftpClient.WriteAllBytes` the service complains the file is not valid XML. If I first write to a temporary file and then use `SftpClient.UploadFile` the transfer is successful.

What's happening?

Using `.WriteAllBytes`:

```
public void Send(string remoteFilePath, byte[] contents)
{
    using(var client = new SftpClient(new ConnectionInfo(/* username password etc.*/)))
    {
        client.Connect();
        client.WriteAllBytes(remoteFilePath, contents);
    }
}
```

Using `.UploadFile`:

```
public void Send(string remoteFilePath, byte[] contents)
{
    var tempFileName = Path.GetTempFileName();
    File.WriteAllBytes(tempFileName, contents);
    using(var fs = new FileStream(tempFile, FileMode.Open))
    using(var client = new SftpClient(new ConnectionInfo(/* username password etc.*/)))
    {
        client.Connect();
        client.UploadFile(fs, targetPath);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
Will in the comments asked how I turn the XML into a byte-array. I didn't think this was relevant, but then again I'm the one asking the question... :P

```
// somewhere else:
// XDocument xdoc = CreateXDoc();

using(var st = new MemoryStream())
{
    using(var xw = XmlWriter.Create(st, new XmlWriterSettings { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8, Indent = true }))
    {
        xdoc.WriteTo(xw);
    }
    return st.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, but you might be able to avoid creating a temporary file in your second snippet by using a `MemoryStream`.

Comment: Seems the issue is how you convert xml to a byte array.  You don't show that, so it's hard to tell.  Writing it to a file first may ... fix it, in some way?  WAG.  Might be that UploadFile uses a different encoding...

Comment: @itsme86: Thanks. While searching around to see if this Q. had been asked before I saw other people using that. This is kinda preferable because it lets me check the files that have been sent for audit/debug purposes.

Comment: @Will: Added this to the Q.

Comment: Does the XML file have a header?  Does it have an encoding attribute, and is it UTF8?

Comment: @Will: Yes. Yes. Yes. :)

Comment: Not sure then... All looks good to someone who hasn't used that particular library.  Might be a bug, or there's something you're missing in the call or setup...  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem using SSH.NET 2016.0.0 from NuGet. But not with 2016.1.0-beta1.

Inspecting the code, I can see that the `SftpFileStream` (what the `WriteAllBytes` uses) keeps writing the same (starting) piece of the data all the time.

It seems that your are suffering from this bug:
https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/issues/70

While the bug description does not make it clear that it's your problem, the commit that fixes it matches the problem I have found:
[Take into account the offset in SftpFileStream.Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) when not writing to the buffer. Fixes issue #70.](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/commit/ad56cc9bdf7cd317b9da8d80adc92db0a7bbb17f)

---

To answer your question: The methods should indeed behave similarly.

Except that `SftpClient.UploadFile` is optimized for uploads of large amount of data, while the `SftpClient.WriteAllBytes` is not. So the underlying implementation is very different.

Also the `SftpClient.WriteAllBytes` does not truncate an existing file. What matters, when you are uploading less data than the existing file have.

Comment: Thanks @Martin, this answers the question. `.UploadFile` more closely matches the use-case so I will use that, but it's good to have the clarification about `.WriteAllBytes`