# C#- Renci.Ssh.Net- Which one gives optimized performance- WriteAllText Vs. UploadFile

Tags: c#, .net, io, sftp, ssh.net

I need to generate multiple XML files at SFTP location from C# code. for SFTP connectivity, I am using Renci.Ssh.net. I found there are different methods to generate files including `WriteAllText()` and `UploadFile()`. I am producing XML string runtime, currently I've used `WriteAllText()` method (just to avoid creating the XML file on local and thus to avoid IO operation).

```
using (SftpClient client = new SftpClient(host,port, sftpUser, sftpPassword))
{
    client.Connect();
    if (client.IsConnected)
    {
        client.BufferSize = 1024;
        var filePath = sftpDir + fileName;
        client.WriteAllText(filePath, contents);
        client.Disconnect();
    }
    client.Dispose();
}
```

Will using `UploadFile()`, either from `FileStream` or `MemoryStream` give me better performance in long run?

The result document size will be in KB, around 60KB.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SftpClient.UploadFile` is optimized for uploads of large amount of data.

But for 60KB, I'm pretty sure that it makes no difference whatsoever. So you can continue using the more convenient `SftpClient.WriteAllText`.

Though, I believe that most XML generators (like .NET [`XmlWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwriter.create#system-xml-xmlwriter-create(system-io-stream)) are able to write XML to `Stream` (it's usually the preferred output API, rather than a string). So the use of `SftpClient.UploadFile` can be more convenient in the end.

---

See also [What is the difference between SftpClient.UploadFile and SftpClient.WriteAllBytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44185392/850848)